# How to pass data from return()->redirect()->back()?

Tags: laravel

I want to add data to the database selecting from the dropdown.
After adding the data it redirects me to the same page.
i want select dropdown to select the same data that i selected before inserting data in database.
I didn't allow me by passing value from return redirect back.
Are there any alternatives?

```
 public function district()
    {
        $data['districts'] = District::all();
        $data['locations'] = Location::paginate(6);

        return view('Backend.pages.dashboard.district',$data);
    }
```

```
      public function addingdistrict(Request $request)
        {

            if($request->isMethod('get'))
            {
                return redirect()->back()->with('danger','Not with URL please');
            }
            if($request->isMethod('post'))
            {
                $data['district_id'] = $request->districtname;
                $data['location'] = $request->locationname;
                if(Location::create($data))
                {

                    return redirect()->back();

                }
            }
        }
```

i want to pass data from addingdistrict return redirect()->back()

Answer (score 3):

```
redirect()->back()->with('message','your message')->with(compact('your_varible'));
```